# Access running aws lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, celery

I want to move Celery that makes excels to AWS-Lambda.

So I've been looking AWS-Lambda.

But not found about get lambda "state".

In Celery, every tasks have `task_id` and can access "state" from `task_id` and also update "state" in tasks.

AWS-Lambda can't access when is running ?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda functions are **stateless**, the are purely functions as a service , if you want to have state, you might want to use **step functions**, which means that they provide **state as a service**. 
For more information about **step fucntions**, read [here](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).